# How can I print the following horizontally, not vertically

Tags: python, for-loop, slice

im triying to print horizontally

```
Text="Si ya conoces Colab, echa un vistazo a este vídeo para obtener información sobre las tablas interactivas"
List= [31,43,15,5,26,32,6,1,3,62,62,62,62,62,62]

for x in List:
  print (Text[x])
```

**Result**

s

o

u

t

c

i

y

And i Wanted

s       o       u   t   c   i   y

nor do I want to do it like this:

```
print(Text[31],Text[43],Text[15],Text[5],Text[26],Text[32],Text[6],Text[1],Text[3],Text[62],Text[62],Text[62],Text[62],Text[62],Text[62])
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, strings are natively indexable. For example:

```
>>> Text = "Si ya conoces Colab, echa un vistazo a este vídeo para obtener información sobre las tablas interactivas"
>>> Text[0]
'S'
>>> Text[1]
'i'
```

With that ability, we can do a list comprehension that iterates your `List` and returns the value of the index in `Text` if the value is not a space. This returns a list where each value is the right letter. We then join that list into a string using a space character to separate each letter.

```
>>> Text = "Si ya conoces Colab, echa un vistazo a este vídeo para obtener información sobre las tablas interactivas"
>>> List = [31,43,15,5,26,32,6,1,3,62,62,62,62,62,62]
>>> print(' '.join([Text[x] for x in List if Text[x] != " "]))
s o u t c i y
```

The list comprehension above is nearly equivalent to this longer bit of code:

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> for x in List:
...     if Text[x] != ' ':
...         new_list.append(Text[x])
...
>>> print(" ".join(new_list))
s o u t c i y
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `sep` keyword arg for `print`, and expand a generator expression into `print`.

```
print(*(Text[x] for x in List if Text[x] != ' '), sep=" ", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, also would do a check to see if the index is in range.

```
for x in l:
 if x < len(text):
    print(text[x], end = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to add it to a string first, and then print it out

```py
text="Si ya conoces Colab, echa un vistazo a este vídeo para obtener información sobre las tablas interactivas"
list= [31,43,15,5,26,32,6,1,3,62,62,62,62,62,62]

output = "" #initialize the output string
for x in list: 
  #continually concat to the output string
  output += text[x]

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for x in List:
    print (Text[x],end="")
```